# c# Listbox and Tabpage

Tags: c#, listbox, tabpage

I have 2 Listbox on different tabpages that uses the same datasource

Basically its tabpage1 + listbox1 and tabpage2 + listbox2

I'm trying to do the following :

When I select Item  from listbox1 on tabpage1 , I want the same item selected to listbox2 on tabpage2

I tried this:

```
listbox1.SelectedItem = listBox2.SelectedItem;
```

also this :

```
string sitem = "";
sitem = listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
listbox2.SelectedItem = sitem
```

nothing works as expected, I'm wondering if its possible ?

Comment: On which event are you trying to set the selectedItem

Comment: in listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: See example at bottom for a possible solution : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Nice, Its exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Finally I made it with the example of PaulF

here is my working code :

```
 private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sitem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        int index = listBox2.FindString(sitem);
        listBox2.SetSelected(index, true);
    }
```

so when I select item in listbox1, it also select it in listbox2

Comment: I guess I should have posted it as an answer, but as I was just directing you to the MS documentation I only felt it worth a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the tabControl is declared as `public` or `internal`. if not then change the tabControl from private to public in the designer.cs file

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;

public System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;
```

and then

```
using (Form form = new Form())
{         
     form.listbox1.SelectedItem = form.listBox2.SelectedItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `SelectedIndex` property of `listbox2`:

```
listbox1.SelectedIndexChanged += delegate(object sndr, EventArgs args)
{
    var lst = (ListBox) sndr;
    listbox2.SelectedIndex = listbox2.Items.IndexOf(lst.SelectedItem);
};
```